# Javascript - Get form by action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display an alert box when a form with certain action is submitted.. 
I'm doing this on jquery :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $("form[action='#jsquick']").submit(function() {
 alert("Signup");

 return false;
 }); 
 </script>
```

What's the equivalent of the code above in pure javascript ?

Answer (score 7):

It would be this:

```
document.querySelector("form[action='#jsquick']").onsubmit = function(){
  alert("Sign up");
  return false; 
}
```

You can use the `querySelector` and `onclick` to the same effect as $("form[action='#jsquick']") and `.submit()` respectively.

Comment: glad to have helped you :) @ShikataGaNai